# Get the number before dot symbol

Tags: php

How to get the number before dot symbol, i try using round() but sometimes give me wrong number for what i need, i have the following calculation, lets say

```
$Calc = 10/3;
$Calc = 3.333333333333333;
```

I'm trying to use round() php function

```
$Calc = 10/3;
$Calc = round(3.333333333333333);
$Calc = 3;
```

but for example if my result is 3.51+

```
$Calc = round(3.51);
$Calc = 4;
```

BUT i just need the 3, not the rest , how can i get that?

Comment: Use floor(); From manual "Returns the next lowest integer value by rounding down value if necessary."

Comment: use this `$Calc = int() $Calc;` it always returns only int values instead of round the values

Comment: @tliokos working perfect, but 1 more question, how i can see if a number have lets say .3333 or is full number with out dot

Comment: @AlinAdrian You can use is_int()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$Calc = 10/3;
$pos = strpos($Calc, '.');
$Calc = substr($Calc, 0, $pos);
```

This will give the all the digits before the decimal.

Answer (score 5):

you could try with `intval()` function

```
echo intval(3.51); // output will be 3
echo intval(10/3); // output will be 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use floor:

```
echo floor(3.99); // 3
echo floor(3.023);// 3
echo floor(4.4);  // 4
echo floor(9.0);  // 9
```